# Specify A type for Response Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Is there a way to specify a type for express's request. I was hoping there was I could make the request object of a custom type.I was looking into possibly extending the router type in order to have this.Or is there a way I can refactor it to make the type the custom type.

```js
app.get('text',function(req: CustomResponse,res,next)
{
//route code here
});
```

This code throws the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>[]): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response<any, number>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
```

So I was wondering the best way to go about this.

Comment: Are you asking how to make TypeScript happy with your current code?  Or are you asking how to tell Express to create your custom response object rather than its own?  Or both?

Comment: I was asking how to create a custom response object rather than its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you'll use its corresponding type and just set a type on your custom req or res inside the function

**Install**

`npm install @types/express --save-dev`

**Code Sample**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';


app.use('text', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

   const body: CustomRequest = req.body;        // req.body or other properties under req
                                                 // and assign it to your corresponding type

});
```

---

In your code, I have noticed that you specify the `req` with `CustomResponse`.

Note that the 1st parameter `req` is a `request` and the 2nd parameter `res` is `response`

Answer (score 0):

Express allows you to easily add to its request or response prototype.  You can see the source that enables that [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L51).  You will need to use the original response object in order to actually send a response so the general model is that you extend the existing object rather than replace it entirely.

Here's a simple example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// add .test() method to the Express response object
app.response.test = function(str) {
    console.log("got our .test() method call");
    this.send(str);
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.test("Hi!!!!!");
});

app.listen(80);
```

In this example, we add a `.test(str)` method to the response object prototype.  So, whenever the response object is passed to an Express request handler, that `.test()` method will be there already and you can see how it is called in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the use case where I wanted to add the type for a custom attribute inside each request. And custom request which would hold the different body according to request.

case 1: Custom attribute inside each request
I am using the name space & adding the custom attribute type for each request.

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    context: {
      authorizerId: string;
      organisationid: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Case 2: Custom request with differnet body

```
a: Custom request body

interfce CustomReqestBody {
name: string;
description: string;
}

b: Custom Request

export interface CustomRequest<B> extends Request {
  body: B;
}

c: Router 

import CustomReqestBody from './path';
import CustomRequest from './path';
mspRouter.post('/', async (request: CustomRequest<CustomReqestBody>, response: Response) => {
  return response.status(200).json({ message: 'Connected!' });
});
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do it for responses as well? I.e. force a certain body type of the response?

Comment: Yes, If you look into express response type.
 export interface Response<ResBody = any> extends core.Response<ResBody> { };

They accept the body and the default value is any.